# Substitute some patterns with skipping others

Tags: unix, sed

My question is how to format file like this:

```
Name 2ndName Surname 879654
Name Surname 546312
```

To This:

```
Name 2ndName,Surname,879654
Name,Surname,546312
```

As you can see difficulty is to save space before Name and 2ndName if sb have 2ndName.
I found this command:

```
 sed -i 's/[[:space:]]/,/' file.txt
```

but it doesnt include possibility of leaving some spaces alone.

Comment: how your actual data looks like?

Comment: You need to be able to define the difference between the spaces you want to replace and the ones you don't. If you can't do that (and you can't show us *meaningfully* representative data) then we can't help you.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, now i remember that my teacher told some exercises are not able to do. I think this is one of them.

Comment: Given just that sample input you could do it by replacing the *last two* spaces in the line. Assuming a surname never has a space in it and neither does that final "code" field.

Answer (score 0):

Given your limited example, this might be someplace for you to start:

```
awk 'NF == 4 {printf "%s %s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4} \
     NF == 3 {printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3} \
     NF > 4 || NF < 3 {print "Error!"}' file.txt
```